# What is a safe distance from a stellar nursery and what will it look like from that distance?

Tags: supernova, nebula, distance

I was designing an arrangement of megastructures which would be hidden within a nebula but for those in the know it would be big location pointer and I have gone for a molecular cloud based on the Orion nebula.

The stellar nursery, the trapezium cluster would be useful for star lifting and mining materials plus the image of a such a densely packed cluster with 1000 stars within a space of 4 light years in diameter will be visually impressive.

Due to the rough environment within a stellar nursery due to wild orbital paths and ejections of the densely packed stars the arrangement of habitat megastructures will need to be outside of the nursery but then I realised that because of supernovas they will need to be much further than I had planned. 50 light years away possibly according to some sources.

My question is: What would be a safe distance from a stellar nursery and what would the nebula and stellar nursery, look like in the sky with the naked eye from that distance?

I am not sure if the nebula will be visible from the relatively close distance from some of the sources I have checked (although i would love it to be visible). So if it is not visible then the question is, what will the stellar nursery which is 4 light years in diameter and surrounding more dispersed stars of the Orion nebula cluster which span 20 light years in diameter, look like with the naked eye from the distance?

Comment: Important detail: safe distance for _what_? meatbag biosphere? Or well shielded super-technology designed to last for highly extended periods of time in that sort of hostile environment?

Comment: @StarfishPrime The megastructures will be to house meatbags, data storage and processors which are not as disposable as the ships sent in to mine and star lift. I was not sure how well shielded the important structures could be? I am happy for them to be as armoured and protected as possible if it means a closer distance.

Comment: I think the risks you need to worry about are: (1) deadly radiation _bursts_ emitted by dying massive stars, and (2) impacts to the planet from loose matter, which is most frequent when a star system is young. Both kinds of disaster can end all life on your planet almost without regard for its tech level. Also, both are _inevitable_ on a long-enough timeline, so a question for you is: what duration do you need for this safe period? 4Bn+ years, to grow a stellar race from scratch? 1K years, for colonizers to settle and move on?

Answer (score 1):

You could actually hide a megastructure within a nebula if it's properly shielded. The increase in radiation within a nebula tops out in the ultraviolet spectrum, and most of it is infrared. A civilization that could build a megastructure could also clean all of the dust out of an area to gather materials for it.

I think the limiter is time frame. Do you expect the megastructure to last millions of years? That would involve planning where the new stars are likely to form and placing your structure accordingly. It isn't the nebula's dust that would be dangerous, since that's basically a hot vacuum.

Thousands of years? Just pick a relatively vacuous area and give it a hard shell.

Hundreds of years? No special requirements beyond radiation shielding and watching for stray rocks.